# Java Mail Internet Address parse bad format attributes without errors.

Tags: java, validation, email, email-validation

I am using Java mail.

The following to string is a good format, and it successfully sends an email.

```
String to = "abc@test.com";
```

Whereas the following to2 string is a bad format, and I expect it to throw an error where it does not.

```
String to2 = 'abctest'
if (StringUtils.hasText(to2)) {
   Address[] toia2 = InternetAddress.parse(to2);
   mailMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toia2);
}
```

It behaves: runs smoothly throw the debugger, no error message in log, but never sends an email...

Could anyone teach me how should I change my code, so that I can have error message thrown upon checking invalid "To", "Cc" etc email address please?

Thank you.

Comment: You should double-check the behavior of `parse`, I know the boolean variant will allow name-only addresses (i.e., no `@foo.bar`) even in strict mode--I'm not sure if the non-boolean variant is also that tolerant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I checked out the code in `mail-1.4`. The code in `InternetAddress.parse` looks very bad to be honest. Any way it does accept that it does most validations but not all. Looking at the class there is a method `validate` that does these validations.

So modifying the code as per below will do it.

```
   public class Sample {

    public static void main(String... args) throws AddressException {
        String to2 = "abctest";
        if (StringUtils.hasText(to2)) {
            InternetAddress[] toia2 = InternetAddress.parse(to2);
            for(InternetAddress address:toia2){
                address.validate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

I am doing the validation of email address above you can add `mailMessage.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, toia2);` in for loop or as you may deem appropriate.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. I have done with the requirements. But to improve it, do you have suggestions on better validating the email addresses please? Thank you.

Comment: This is one of the valid ways. Many liberaries provide this too e.g. Apache coomons has EmailValidator which simply takes a String and validates it. But no need to use that only for this reason.